# In R XML Package, what is the difference between xmlParse and xmlTreeParse?

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

When would I want to use the `xmlParse` function versus the `xmlTreeParse` function? Also, when are parameter values `useInternalNodes=TRUE` or `asText=TRUE` useful?

For example:

```
library("XML")
nct_url <- "http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00112281?resultsxml=true"
xml_doc <- xmlParse(nct_url, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

vs.

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(getURL(nct_url), useInternalNodes=TRUE)
top <- xmlRoot(doc)
top[["keyword"]]
xmlValue(top[["start_date"]])
xmlValue(top[["location"]])
```

People seem to use the `xmlTreeParse` function for getting a non-repeating node via the $doc$children$... traversal. But I am not sure I understand when each approach is best. Parsing XML is one of the reasons to almost abandon R and learn Python. Lack of for-dummies examples without being forced to buy a book.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here some feedback after using XML package.

- `xmlParse` is a version of `xmlTreeParse` where argument `useInternalNodes` is set to TRUE.
- If you want to get an R object use `xmlTreeParse`. This can be not very efficient and unnecessary if you want just to extract partial part of the xml document.
- If you don't want to get an R object, just a c pointer, use `xmlParse`. But you should know some `xpath` bases to manipulate the result.
- Use `asText=TRUE` if you have a text not a file or an url as input.

Here an example where I show the difference between the 2 functions:

```
txt <- "<doc>
          <el> aa </el>
       </doc>"
library(XML)
res <- xmlParse(txt,asText=TRUE)
res.tree <- xmlTreeParse(txt,asText=TRUE)
```

Now inspecting the 2 objects:

```
class(res)
[1] "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"
> class(res.tree)
[1] "XMLDocument"         "XMLAbstractDocument"
```

You see that res is an **internal** document. It is pointer to a C object. 
res.tree is an R object. You can get its attributes like this :

```
 res.tree$doc$children
$doc
<doc>
 <el>aa</el>
</doc>
```

For res, you should use a valid `xpath` request and one of theses functions ( `xpathApply`, `xpathSApply` ,`getNodeSet`) to inspect it. for example:

```
xpathApply(res,'//el')
```

Once you create a valid Xml Node , you can apply `xmlValue`, `xmlGetAttr`,..to extract node information. So here this 2 statements are equivalent:

```
## we have already an R object, just apply xmlValue to the right child
xmlValue(res.tree$doc$children$doc)
## xpathSApply create an R object and pass it to
xpathSApply(res,'//el',xmlValue)
```