# Unknown IO errorfailed to load external entity

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to learn text mining in R.

I don't know why this error comes?

```
library(XML)
xml.url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
plants <- xmlParse(xml.url)
plants.l <- xmlToList(plants)
length(plants.l)
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You have to add asText=TRUE to your function. However, it does not like the XML format of the website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R xmlParse/xmlTreeParse unknown IO error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230888/r-xmlparse-xmltreeparse-unknown-io-error)

Answer (score 4):

You've come with an issue of `XML` package. It doesn't work great with redirects (`http -> https`, your URL starting with `http`) and with `https`.

You can use some other package to download the file. Here is an example with `httr`.

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
xml.url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
plants <- xmlParse(rawToChar(GET(xml.url)$content))
plants.l <- t(xmlToList(plants, simplify = TRUE))
length(plants.l)
```

I've also added `t()` and `simplify = TRUE` to have a nice and plain list in R, as a result.