# R turning list to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have three list  from a web scraping fishing some data around.

This is the code I have used (credit to David Jankoski for the idea of it):

```
> `x %>%
   html_nodes(".survey-row") %>%
   html_attr("data-url")
   list1 <- x
       [1] "http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118"
       [2] ...`
```

This element has got

```
 `class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"`
```

I would like to turn this list (and the other two - very similar to this) into a data frame.
Yet, I have tried the

1.
     `list1.a <- as.data.frame(read_html(list1) %>% html_table(fill=TRUE))`

and

2.
      `list.1.a <-do.call(rbind.data.frame, list1)`

options, but without any good result, receiving error messages such as:

```
   1. `Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
   no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class   "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

   2. Error in xi[[j]] : object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable `
```

I have tried to find suggestions here but the one I have caught apparently they don't work. I apologize in case I haven't noticed some fitting question/answer.

Again, I'd like to convert this in a data frame to better manage the data and to eventually merge them into another greater data frame through, if possible, a command that could 'run' fast enough (without any `Sys.sleep()` issue, for instance. 
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following-

```
list_df <- purrr::map(.x = list1, .f = tibble::as_data_frame)
```

list_df elements should correspond to data frames.

Comment: Thanks for the help, to start.
This is the error message I receive:
     `Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, ...) : 
       cannot coerce class ""externalptr"" to a data.frame`

Comment: Hmm, have you checked out this thread?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379348/externalptr-error-in-r-using-xml-data
Will probably be of help getting rid of this error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. but the message I receive is:

`Error in xml[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose this without having access to reproducible error. Check out `reprex` (https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) and copy-paste your code and error here, which would make it really easy for others to come up with a solution.