# How to convert hmtl_node to list in R

Tags: html, r, xml

I have scraped a bunch of data from the web:

```
source <- "https://www.ifad.org/en/web/operations/-/project/1100000001" #example data
html_out <- read_html(source)
temp_list <- html_out %>%
    html_node(".project-row")

> temp_list
{html_node}
<div class="m-3 project-row">
 [1] <dd class="project-status mt-3">\r\n                                        <span>Status: Closed</span>\r\n                           ...
 [2] <dt class="project-row-title">Country</dt>
 [3] <dd class="project-row-text">\r\n                                            <a href="/en/web/operations/w/country/dominican-republic ...
 [4] <dt class="project-row-title">Approval Date</dt>
 [5] <dd class="project-row-text">19 December 1979</dd>
 [6] <dt class="project-row-title">Duration</dt>
 [7] <dd class="project-row-text">1979 - 1988</dd>
 [8] <dt class="project-row-title">Sector</dt>
 [9] <dd class="project-row-text">Settlement</dd>
[10] <dt class="project-row-title">\r\nTotal Project Cost                                </dt>
```

I now want to perform a number of operations on these data, which probably require a list format and should return a list format. For example the following things:

```
temp_list <- temp_list %>%
    gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", ., perl = TRUE) %>% # removing multiple spaces
    gsub("\r\n", "", .) # remove \r\n

for (j in 1:length(temp_list)) {
        temp_list[j] <- #do more stuff here
        }
```

I don't really understand how html_nodes work yet, but apparently not like lists. `length(temp_list)` yields `2` instead of 10, for example. The `gsub()` command doesn't return a list, but one long string. I tried `lapply(X = ., FUN = function (t) gsub(pattern = "^ *|(?<= ) | *$", replacement = "", x = t, fixed = TRUE))` to solve that problem, but it returns an error: `cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'`

How do I make a list or another workable format out of the html_node? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513555/15972591) it was proposed to use `bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(temp_list ), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))`, but that only yields `m-3 project-row`. I tried to use `xmlValue()` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384940/15972591) as well, but without success.

All of this worked in a previous version of my script, where I had simply written (even though admittedly not very elegantly):

```
temp_list <- html_out%>%
    html_nodes(".project-row") %>%
    as_list(.) %>%
    unlist(., use.names= FALSE) %>%
    as.list(.) %>%
    gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", ., perl = TRUE) %>% # removing multiple spaces
    gsub("\r\n", "", .) # remove \r\n
```

For some reason it doesn't work anymore, even though I don't remember to have changed anything on this part of my code or on the input data.

Comment: Can you share the url of the webpage from where you are scraping the data?

Comment: It was this page: https://www.ifad.org/en/web/operations/-/project/1100000001. I added it in the question.

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the link? What is your expected output?

Comment: The final expected output is a table with several columns and two rows which contains all the data from this page. E.g. Approval Date: 19 December 1979; Duration: 1979 - 1988. I had already written the script to do that and it worked before. My question here refers to how to transform the html_node type into a list (my expected output). I want a list to read out the data from the node by using `temp_list[j]` and to apply commands like `gsub()`, which work on lists but not on html_node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function which I was searching was `html_children()`.

The script now reads like this:

```
temp_list <- html_out %>%
    html_node(".project-row") %>% 
    html_children %>% 
    html_text() %>%
    gsub("\r\n", "", .) %>% # remove \r\n
    gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", ., perl = TRUE) # removing multiple spaces
```

Applying `html_children` converts `temp_list` from an object of class `xml_node` to a `xml_nodeset`. `xml_nodeset` can be used similar to a list, for example by addressing single elements via `temp_list[j]`. Applying then `html_text` on the `xml_nodeset` retains the list-like structure and does not concatenate the elements together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html_text` to extract only the text from the nodes and apply the `gsub` code on it.

```
library(rvest)

source <- "https://www.ifad.org/en/web/operations/-/project/1100000001" #example data
html_out <- read_html(source)
temp_list <- html_out %>%
  html_node(".project-row") %>%
  html_text()


temp_list %>%
  gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", ., perl = TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("[\r\n]", "", .)
```

Comment: The problem is that this returns all elements concatenated together in one string. How will I be able to distinguish one element from the other then? I would want to use something like `temp_list[1]` to receive `Status: Closed`, `temp_list[2]` to receive `Country` and so on to build my table.